# Generating Perfect Squares python

Tags: python

I am trying to write the simplest code possible that will continuously print out Perfect Squares. My code so far reads this

```
x = 1
y = 1
while True:
    final = x * y
    print final
    x = x + 1
   y = y + 1
```

When I run it, I get a syntax error. The red bit is on the "final" in "print final"

Apologies if it is a really basic error, but I'm stumped.

Thanks for taking the time to read this

Comment: The last line is not properly indented (must be one char to the right).

Comment: @Jan-PhilipGehrcke Either way wouldn't that raise an `Indentation` error?

Comment: It would, and I presume that this is the next error he is observing after having solved the `print` problem, right?

Comment: why don't drop y from your equation and do final = x * x or x ** 2

Answer (score 5):

I assume you're using Python 3. [`print`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#print) is now a function in Python 3.

Do `print(final)` instead of `print final`.

Also, it seems like your `x` and `y` values are holding the same thing. Why not discard one of them and use just one?

```
x = 1
while True:
    final = x * x
    print(final)
    x = x + 1
```

Or better yet, use the builtin exponentiation operator `**`.

```
x = 1
while True:
    final = x **2
    print(final)
    x += 1
```

Also, your code seems to be going into an infinite loop. You may need a condition to `break` it.

For example, if you want to break when `x` reaches `10`, just add a condition in the `while` loop, like follows:

```
x = 1
while True:
    final = x **2
    print(final)
    x += 1
    if x == 10:
        break
```

**OR** Specify a condition in the `while`statement, like follows:

```
x = 1
while x < 10:
    final = x **2
    print(final)
    x += 1
```

**OR** Use a `for` loop.

```
for i in range(10):
    print(i**2)
```

Comment: I like this answer because it offers many improvements to the original code that are at different levels - i.e. it doesn't just jump straight to the end, it offers incremental solutions similar in style to the OP code.

Answer (score 2):

In Python 3, [`print` is no longer a statement but a function](http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function), so you must enclose what you want to print in parentheses:

```
print(final)
```

[Here's](http://docs.python.org/3.0/library/functions.html#print) a link about the function.

---

You also have an IndentationError, `y = y + 1` should be given a space.

And you can simplify that to `y += 1` (which is the same thing, in regards to integers)

---

You can also add a condition to the while-loop:

```
x = 0
while x < 5:
    print x ** 2
    x += 1
```

Prints:

```
0
1
4
9
16
```

Answer (score 1):

I would reccomend using Python 3 if you're not already. Also, as x and y are the same value at all times you only need one of them. So instead of reading:

```
x = 1
y = 1
while True:
    final = x * y
    print final
    x = x + 1
    y = y + 1
```

You should write:

```
x = 1

while True:

    final = x * x

    print(final)

    x = x + 1
```

Hope this helped!
     Jake.